# Erro ao obter licença de desenvolvedor no Windows 8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone

No Visual Studio Community 2013, para o desenvolvimento de aplicações para Windows Phone, exibe o seguinte erro ao tentar obter a licença de desenvolvedor: Título da Mensagem -> Não foi possível obter sua licença de desenvolvedor para Windows 8.1 Conteúdo da Mensagem -> Erro 0x80070422: O serviço não pode ser iniciado porque está desativado ou não tem dispositivos ativados associados.

Comment: Bem vindo, Tente habilitar atualização automática do windows na lista de serviços. Não esqueça de fazer um tour aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

[image: Erro]

De acordo com esta resposta no [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/26835764-8d87-4fa5-8bac-0750528d6fd0/we-couldnt-get-your-developer-license-for-windows-81?forum=csharpgeneral), o problema deve ser resolvido seguindo os seguintes passos:

1. Clique em Iniciar, clique em Executar, digite services.msc e, em seguida, clique em OK.
2. Na lista de serviços, localize o Windows Update e, em seguida, clique em Propriedades.
3. Na lista Tipo de inicialização, clique em automático e, em seguida, clique em Aplicar.
4. Se o status do serviço está definido como Parado, clique em Iniciar e, em seguida, clique em OK.

[image: OK]